# Why does the 2-D vector space would imply the splitting field?

Tags: field-theory

[image]

Why does the 2-D vector space would imply the splitting field?

Answer (score 0):

$Z_3(i)$ is not merely a 2d-vector space it s quotient ring of $Z_3[x]$ by a maximal ideal generated by $x^2+x+2$.